# xsl:for-each elements that have attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<Books>
<Book Cover="Audiobook" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <Title>Middlesex: A Novel</Title>
  <FBT>The Woman Warrior</FBT>
  <FBT>The House on Mango Street</FBT>
  <Isbn>0312427735</Isbn>
  <Author>
    <Name>
      <First>Jeffrey</First>
      <Last>Eugenides</Last>
    </Name>
    <Contact Office="Office1">
      <Phone>110-222-3333</Phone>
    </Contact>
  </Author>
  <Publisher>Picador</Publisher>
  <Year Edition="1">2002</Year>
</Book>
<Book Cover="Audiobook" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <Title>Me Talk Pretty One Day</Title>
  <FBT>Dress Your Family in Corduroy and Denim</FBT>
  <FBT>Naked</FBT>
  <Isbn>9780316776967</Isbn>
  <Author>
    <Name>
      <First>David</First>
      <Last>Sedaris</Last>
    </Name>
    <Contact Office="Office1">
      <Phone>119-222-3333</Phone>
    </Contact>
   </Author>
  <Publisher>Back Bay Books</Publisher>
  <Year Edition="2">2001</Year>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

the main issue that I am having is when I try to iterate inside my xslt code

```
<xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
```

It does not pass through to any of the books that I mentioned. I tried looking up why this can be the issue, unsure still I removed the attributes from one of the book instances and it finally was able to pass through to the child elements so I can put the data into a table.
My first question is why does having attributes inside my book element even have a impact on my for-each?

Secondly is there a work around for this? I would like to keep the attributes inside book.

EDIT: Here is the part where I do the loop

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
          <tr style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: verdana">
            <td>

              <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>

            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Isbn"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Author"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Publisher"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the namespace on your elements.
So define a namespace on your `xsl:stylesheet` element with

```
xmlns:bk="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
```

which is set as the default on your `Book` element, making it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bk="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
...
```

And then apply this change to your template by changing it to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Books/bk:Book">
      <tr style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: verdana">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="bk:Title"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="bk:Isbn"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(bk:Author/bk:Name/bk:First,' ', bk:Author/bk:Name/bk:Last)"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="bk:Publisher"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="bk:Year"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The wrapping template could be removed.
The result is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the correct syntax

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
     <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
     <xsl:value-of select="FBT" /> 
 </xsl:for-each>
```

If you are using the same way it should work to get title and FBT from your XML. If possible try to populate in a table the complete XML and check where went wrong. From the syntax point of view, it's correct according to [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_for_each.asp)

Surprisingly the following XML is working fine, there might be a problem with a namespace(xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"). Please check once...

```
    <Books>
<Book Cover="Audiobook" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <Title>Middlesex: A Novel</Title>
  <FBT>The Woman Warrior</FBT>
  <FBT>The House on Mango Street</FBT>
  <Isbn>0312427735</Isbn>
  <Author>
    <Name>
      <First>Jeffrey</First>
      <Last>Eugenides</Last>
    </Name>
    <Contact Office="Office1">
      <Phone>110-222-3333</Phone>
    </Contact>
  </Author>
  <Publisher>Picador</Publisher>
  <Year Edition="1">2002</Year>
</Book>
<Book Cover="Audiobook" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
  <Title>Me Talk Pretty One Day</Title>
  <FBT>Dress Your Family in Corduroy and Denim</FBT>
  <FBT>Naked</FBT>
  <Isbn>9780316776967</Isbn>
  <Author>
    <Name>
      <First>David</First>
      <Last>Sedaris</Last>
    </Name>
    <Contact Office="Office1">
      <Phone>119-222-3333</Phone>
    </Contact>
   </Author>
  <Publisher>Back Bay Books</Publisher>
  <Year Edition="2">2001</Year>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: yeah it is very odd.. i put a edit to show how my loop runs tho its very similar to yours

Comment: Please check now found the issue. If you got satisfied and issue resolved upvote for the answer :) Thx